# ServletOutputStreamWrapper modification in dd4t 1.31

Tags: dd4t

As per example site available in DD4T 1.31, ServletOutputStreamWrapper in package org.dd4t.springmvc.view.model is using two functions which are available in servlet specifications 3.1. Our websphere is currently on version 3.0.

```
public boolean isReady() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
             public void setWriteListener(WriteListener arg0) {
              TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

My Question is, Can I remove these two functions to make it as per serverlet 3.0 specifications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can - that servletoutputstream is only used by weblogic - every other application server uses the printwriter.

Comment: Thanks Rogier, As we are not using weblogic So Can I completly remove this class from my application?

Comment: The class has references so you'd have to remove those too (you could run into runtime errors).